# Do you repent by your own actions or by God's forgiveness?

Tags: biblical-basis, sin

This is a question I've been wrestling with lately as a recent convert to Christianity. Even though I make contrition and feel repentance for sins I commit, I  worry that unless I do something to 'balance out' that sin, it will remain valid in the eyes of God. Therefore I, and this is where I hope people of this site might reserve judgement, do things in my life that stretch me in order to punish myself in some manner eg working late, not doing stuff I enjoy.

I know this seems unbiblical (especially eg Ephesians 2 9) but this concern always remains. What are the perspectives of the people here? Is this valid and Christian, or just my anxiety and eagerness to be a good convert striking me? What does the Bible say about this, and about the mechanisms of repentance?

Thanks so much - any help would be appreciated

Comment: Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

Comment: What are the perspectives here ? I think you will find many different perspectives, possibly almost as many perspectives as there are persons accessing the service. This site is about _comparative_ Christianity, examining self-identifying Christian groups and denominations and asking questions about them. Personally, we each tread our own path, as do you, yourself. And God shall judge each one, as individuals.

Comment: Psalm 103:12  Exactly how far is the east from the west?  If you have accessed God's forgiveness through Jesus you may trust in it completely.

Comment: Which faith tradition are you asking from?  There may be some subtle differences in teaching on this; as you've asked it the question is too broad and borders on a "Truth" question which this format does not handle.

Comment: It seems odd that neither answer shows that it is God who grants repentance. Our change of life is His responsibility not ours, we merely respond with new hearts and minds.

Comment: @ermatveit “There may be some sins of which a man cannot speak, but there is no sin which the blood of Christ cannot wash away.” - Charles Spurgeon. —-> Just a comment here, but that quote expresses that God has seen it all and forgiven much worse. This speaker is reformed theology preacher and believes in election (as does the Bible imo). But all of Christendom believes the most egregious sin is not too much to be forgiven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question. I can understand your desire to 'balance out' your sins. That is a very natural human inclination - which is why most religions rely on our good works to get us into heaven. What makes Christianity different is that it's not about our good deeds outweighing or balancing out our bad deeds. On the contrary, Christianity is about becoming entirely new creations (2 Cor 5:17) by the power of Christ's death and resurrection - with new hearts, new desires, new loves, and a new power through Christ's Spirit to love the living God and obey Him.

But if we are entirely new creatures why do we still sin? There is an old preacher saying that might help you - "On the cross, Jesus set us free from the penalty of sin and the power of sin, but we are not yet free from the presence of sin." In other words, Jesus cleansed us from guilt and gave us power over sin by the Spirit, but we are still in a battle with sin each day. That is why Galatians 5 depicts the struggle between the flesh and the Spirit.

When we sin as a Christian, it is still God who purifies us - there is nothing we can do to purify ourselves - no good deed can cleanse our conscience or make us right with God. As the following verse shows:

1 John 1:9

> If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just and will forgive us our sins and **purify us** from all unrighteousness. (NIV)

But the Bible is also clear that when we first become Christians we are like little babies - we still barf on ourselves and mess up a lot. So we need to grow up and overcome sin. Hebrews 5 and 1 John talk about those who are new Christians versus the mature, who can distinguish good from evil and walk in victory over sin. But how do we grow up?

2 Peter 1 is my absolute favorite passage about how to grow up as a Christian - we need to learn about God's Word and how to be a Christian (which is exactly what you are doing), we need to practice what we learn, and we need to recognize it is God's divine power in us that transforms us.

2 Peter 1:3-9

> His divine power has given us everything we need for a godly life through our knowledge of him who called us by his own glory and goodness. 4 Through these he has given us his very great and precious promises, so that through them you may participate in the divine nature, having escaped the corruption in the world caused by evil desires.
>
> 5 For this very reason, make every effort to add to your faith goodness; and to goodness, knowledge; 6 and to knowledge, self-control; and to self-control, perseverance; and to perseverance, godliness; 7 and to godliness, mutual affection; and to mutual affection, love. 8 For if you possess these qualities **in increasing measure**, they will keep you from being ineffective and unproductive in your knowledge of our Lord Jesus Christ. 9 But whoever does not have them is nearsighted and blind, forgetting that they **have been cleansed** from their past sins. (NIV)

Here is another great verse emphasizing that it is God who cleanses us by His Spirit because of His mercy. There is nothing we can do to earn it.

Titus 3:4-7

> But when the kindness and love of God our Savior appeared, 5 he saved us, **not because of righteous things we had done, but because of his mercy. He saved us through the washing of rebirth and renewal by the Holy Spirit**, 6 whom he poured out on us generously through Jesus Christ our Savior, 7 so that, having been justified by his grace, we might become heirs having the hope of eternal life.

I hope those thoughts are helpful to you in some way and may Christ fill you with His Spirit and the peace that comes from resting in His love and mercy. Blessings on the journey.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Brilliant answer that doesn't stray from the text. Take note of agarza's edit and please continue to bring the word in your answers. +1

Comment: Thank you - yes, I accepted the edits suggested by agarza - they were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sin is offense against God.  Some sins are also offense against others.  Sin can be seen as *injustice*.  Sin hurts God and possibly others.  It's extremely important to distinguish the two.
Forgiveness from God is *separate* than forgiveness from others.  It is also separate than forgiving yourself.

Repentance is more than expressing regret.  It has the following elements:

1. Recognizing that we did wrong (admitting) because we "walked in the wrong path."
2. Resolving to turn 180 degrees to start walking in the right path.
3. Willingness to repair the injustice against God
4. Willingness to repair the injustice against others (if necessary)

Repentance is our subjective experience, but **forgiveness is what God does and we don't have to feel it**.  We only need to know (by faith) that God has forgiven us and to trust God that He will "forget" (i.e. don't count it against us anymore).  The injustice against God is erased by Jesus's sacrifice.  We do not need to do anything to earn this forgiveness from God once we have done proper repentance.  God will no longer judge us because of the sins that we already repent.  We can then forgive ourselves based on God's forgiveness.

What you feel maybe the effect of injustice toward others.  It is normal to feel that you are responsible to repair the damage.  In Catholicism it's called doing penance.  Rather than "balancing" to earn God's forgiveness, see it more as an inner motivation to repair our relationship with those we hurt.  This feeling is natural, and it's part of the operation of conscience, as well as coming from the wellspring of love in our heart.

It's sometimes not easy to procure other's forgiveness when we sin against them, although it is NOT required to obtain forgiveness from God.  It is also normal not to be able to forgive ourselves when we have not obtained their forgiveness.  When our sin also affects others, we **do** need to ask them to forgive us in addition to asking God for forgiveness.  Although we may die before they forgive us, as long as God has already forgiven us we will not be judged.  Thus our salvation is not conditioned on their forgiveness.  But proper repentance needs to include our willingness to seek their forgiveness and our willingness to repair the injustice toward them.

I hope the above sheds some light on the mechanism of repentance and how it links to forgiveness and penance.

**To conclude**, we repent by our own actions but we know and trust that God does his part to forgive us when we do proper repentance.  In addition, when we sin against others, our repentance also need to include 1) seeking forgiveness from those we hurt and 2) our willingness to repair the damage we caused.

Comment: ''  don't have to feel it ' ( ! ) ... Abel **obtained witness** that he was righteous ... ' Heb 11:4

Comment: @NigelJ What I meant is that feeling is *optional*, which is OP's issue that he feels not forgiven by God.

Comment: _I said, I will confess my transgressions unto the LORD; and thou forgavest the iniquity of my sin. Selah._ Psalm 32:5. David had only just willed to confess. Before the words left his mouth (for God knows the thoughts, Matthew 6:8, before they are spoken) David _knew_ that God had forgiven him. Such is justification by faith. When it happens, _we know it_. Amen.

Comment: @NigelJ I agree with you that David *knew* by faith, so I don't understand why you make an issue here.  I think we both agree that *knowing* and *feeling* is not the same.  We know (by faith) that God forgives us.  My point is simply feeling is optional.  In conservative Christianity feeling *follows* knowing.  It's liberal Christians (influenced by Romanticism) who prioritize feeling over knowing.

Comment: 'True religion's more than notion ; something must be known and _felt_. ' From John Hart's Hymns and from the title of the book (which I recommend) [_More than Notion_](https://www.theparsonspages.co.uk/more-than-notion/) by J H Alexander. I know of my justification, partly through understanding what it means but also by the ministrations of the Spirit, in unburdening me from the convictions (which are given of He, himself) and the entrances into spiritual experience which I am given. As William Huntington said 'Some people assume that _thinking_ is _believing_.'

Comment: @NigelJ Again, I agree with you.  But when one of them is missing (not all the time, but on occasions) as we read in Job or in some other Psalms, don't you think we better rely on our mind to pull us through?  Especially when something bad happens, I often have to depend on my mind (to recall the promises of God); feelings may follow later. Even Mother Teresa [doesn't feel God's closeness for years](https://smmsisters.org/sisters-stories/the-doubts-of-a-saint-mother-teresas-unfelt-faith): " she **felt** abandoned by God; that even as she promised Jesus' love to others, she no longer felt it"!

Comment: If the Spirit departs and leaves us bereft, there is but one thing to be done, above all others - to seek why it is so and to remedy it, if it is within our own capacity, or speak to others if that is required. My spirit cannot rest if I have not His presence.

Answer (score -1):

One doesn't "feel repentance", one feels guilt.
Except for brief guilt that leads to repentance, guilt is a negative emotion, an unnecessary weight to be avoided.

To repent literally means to change one's mind, so that one thinks differently.
This causes a change in one's behaviour and an improvement of one's character.
Repentance is a positive action, a necessary goal to be desired.

One cannot "balance out" a sin.
The penalty for sin is perpetual death.
If you think you are able to "do something", you are overestimating yourself and following your own pride.
There is nothing you can do to make up for it.
Other than accepting the death penalty, you are incapable of paying for your sins.

But Christianity is all about forgiveness, not blame.

When you can:

- Look at what you did.
- Honestly understand how wrong it was.
- See that you have changed your outlook on life.
- Know that you will never make that mistake again.
- Forgive yourself for your former-self's behaviour.

You can know that:

- God has also forgiven you.
- God has paid your debt for you.

Repentance requires an actual change in your attitude and behaviour.
That is all that is asked of you.

Comment: Repentance _matanoia_ is a matter of the _noia_ - the mind.

Comment: @NigelJ, right.  To repent means to change one's mind or to think differently.  I've edited the "is a change" to make this more obvious.

Comment: _Metanoia_ is not a 'change of mind'. That is not what _meta_ does grammatically. _Meta_ is a powerful piece of language that layers one thing over another. John the Baptist describes himself as 'the friend of the bridegroom who stands by'. The Olde English equivalent to _meta_ is 'mid' as in 'midwife'. Repentance is _another mind_ that is to say another mind than the carnal mind. It is a filling up of the interior with word (see Genesis 25, camels and see filling up of stone waterpots John 2).

Comment: @NigelJ says "*Metanoia is not a 'change of mind'.*".  Bible dictionaries don't agree.  For instance, [G3340 - metanoeō - Strong's Greek Lexicon](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g3340/kjv/tr/0-1/) says "*to change one's mind, i.e. to repent*".
And "*to think differently*".
And "*to change one's mind for the better, heartily to amend with abhorrence of one's past sins*".

Comment: That's why we need to get 'beyond the basics'. As in Daniel B Wallace's _Beyond the Basics_.